# using setting to shrink the space between columns in lyx beamer

Tags: tables, lyx

I insert a table into beamer environment in lyx. there is a large space between columns, is there a way to shrink the intercolumn space and make table compact ? I am not write latex code so I do not know how to change the code but hope to find a solution using settings ? Thank you. 
Attach pic is the snapshot of the table[image]

Comment: please upload the code to find the problem

Comment: Please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample